# How do I find out the number of visitors to a Joomla page that does not have an article?

Tags: joomla

I have a Joomla page which is a menu item of type 'wrapper' and which also displays a couple of modules beside that wrapper.

I can see how many hits an article has had, however, this page has no article, how do I know how many visitors it has had?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla doesn't keep track of the number of hits on pages, it keeps track on some content items, such as articles, so, when an article is displayed within a page, it increases the number of hits for that article.

Now, if you want to know the number of hits on a non article page, you have 3 options:

- Add an empty article to that page and then look at the hits on that article..
- Use a `grep` command on your logs to know the number of hits.
- Check Google Analytics for the number of hits on that page.

The latter is the simplest, but it requires that you install Google Analytics on the website (or at least on that particular page).